# Odoo: How to set import template default for model

Tags: odoo, odoo-16, odoo-17

I saw the following code in the crm.lead model and tried to do the same for my model, and I also have an xls file in the same folder structure, but when I go to the import section, there is no suggestion to download the template default

```
@api.model
def get_import_templates(self):
    return [{
        'label': _('Import Template for Leads & Opportunities'),
        'template': '/crm/static/xls/crm_lead.xls'
    }]
```